# Request is stuck when password is wrong (Async/Await)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So,i am quite new to async await.But i thought i should implement it in one of project to see how it really works and understands totally.But i am stuck & not able to understand what really is happening.

So in my PERN app, i am trying to log a user, so the request comes from the front end, with username and password, and then i use the findOne(sequelize), method to find if the user exist or not, and also doing the same for the password, but comparing it using bcrypt compare function.

But when the user enters a wrong email or password the whole response is stuck somehow,as i am getting a response of 500, though i have handled the  error for these kind of events.

I am saying it is stuck because i added a console at the bottom of that findOne and compare function, they are not logging, but as soon as the email or password is correct the response is received.

```
 const { email, password } = req.body;

  console.log({ email, password });

  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

  const passwordMatch = await bcyptjs.compare(password, user.password);
  console.log('Cant Reach here when the fields are incorrect', password);
  console.log('Cant Reach here when the fields are incorrect', user.password);


  if (!user &&  !passwordMatch) {
    return next({
      message: 'Username or Password is incorrect.',
      statusCode: 400,
    });
  }
```

Comment: are there any unhandled Promise rejections logging out?

Comment: it should be *or* `if (!user || !passwordMatch) {`

Comment: i fixed it somehow, what i did is i added the !user just after checking for user, and the same for password,
Checking both at the same time is not working, don't know why,strangely i did the same thing in mongoose and it worked fine..

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo (bcypt vc bcrypt) :)
And I think the method rejects when the fields do not match. So you should wrap the compare in a try/catch block.
Or you could use the sync version

```
bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
```

which will return true or false

Comment: I don't think that is the issue,
as the imported name is same, though i changed it but still no luck,
and for handling errors i have 
async  handler middleware,
  asyncCatch = (fn) => (req, res, next) =>
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing a try catch block to handle errors !

```
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    
      console.log({ email, password });

     try{

      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
    
      const passwordMatch = await bcyptjs.compare(password, user.password);
      console.log('Cant Reach here when the fields are incorrect', password);
      console.log('Cant Reach here when the fields are incorrect', user.password);
    
    }catch(e){
    console.log(e.message)
    console.log(e.statusCode)
}
```